# How can I remove the cartridge from my kitchen tap?

Tags: plumbing, cartridge

I have a monobloc kitchen mixer tap and need to get the cartridge out. Have got the handle and cover off, and can see the cartridge - it is recessed.

There is no nut to twist it seems (all the YouTube videos seem to have a nut). Just 4 little metal clip looking things - I'm not sure if these are holding it in or not.

It is possible its just stuck in there with limescale also..

Wondering if I should just be pulling outwards, or trying to twist. Or going to buy some WD40. Any advice/help would be amazing!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not use WD-40 on potable water plumbing. I'm not familiar with that particular setup, but I imagine the "clips" either unclip, or are all 4 joined into a "nut" that would *like* a special wrench but which might be movable by tapping on them carefully. Don't forget to turn the water supply off first (many people do, and then it gets exciting...)

Answer (score 2):

Right, so I sorted it. Will post solution here for anyone else who comes across this weird fitting!

Basically the threaded part is actually kind of a nut. So use a wrench to twist this anticlockwise, whilst trying not to ruin the thread!The cartridge then just pulls out.

Comment: With the "nut" out, could you post pictures of both sides of it? I'd expect notches on the side that faces out, rather than "grab onto the threads and try not to ruin them" - I wonder if it was installed backwards, since I don't see any of those in the assembled pictures.